# correlation between transformed variables

Tags: correlation, data-transformation

If I know the value of $Cor(X, Y)$, can one derive the value of  $Cor(f(X), f(Y))$, with

$$
f(x) = \frac{\exp(x)}{1 + \exp(x)} ?
$$

PS: Cor = Pearson correlation

Comment: is this a home work? why don't you simply plug the function into the definition of correlation?

Comment: Hi @Aksakal: It's not homework. I have tried to do as you suggest but haven't succeeded to arrive at sthg. Is it that obvious? Any hint?

Comment: no, it's not obvious that you should be able to arrive to an analytical expression as a result.

Comment: No. E.g. suppose the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is uniform among $$(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (a,b)$$ If $(a,b)=(1,2)$ you will get one correlation for $X,Y$ and another correlation for $f(X),f(Y)$. If $(a,b)=(5,6)$ you will get the same correlation for $X,Y$ but a different correlation for $f(X),f(Y)$. So there is no way to write the correlation of $f(X), f(Y)$ as a function of the correlation of $X,Y$.

Comment: The answer is purely conditional: if you know the joint distribution of $(X,Y),$ you can compute the correlation of any functions of these variables.  Otherwise, there is little one can say.  Indeed, I believe the set of pairs $(\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y),\ \operatorname{Cor}(f(X),f(Y)))$ as $(X,Y)$ ranges over all random variables (defined on a sufficiently rich space) will fill the interior of the rectangle $[-1,1]\times[-1,1].$